# Value is not reflecting in bean class after selecting from updated selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working with selectOneMenu of primefaces and i am trying update one selectOneMenu after salect value from other selectOneMenu.
With this code every thing is working fine i am getting updates value in selectOnemenu. But problem is when i am select value from updated selectOneMenu is not reflecting in bean 
menas after click on button i am getting null value in my bean class
here in this code i am trying to update selectOneMenu with id "deviceosName" after selecting value from selectOneMenu with id "manufectureName". but after select value from selectOneMenu with id "deviceosName" 
not reflecting in bean class.
I am not able figure out the problem. can somebody help me ?

```
<h:form>
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />

        <p:panel id="os_version_panel" header="Os Version">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" title="Os Version"
                style="width:40%;height:20%;padding:10%;padding-left:30%">

                <h:outputLabel for="manufectureName" value="Manufecture Name:*"
                    style="float:right;font-size:15px;width:200px" />
                <p:spacer width="20" height="50" />

                <p:selectOneMenu id="manufectureName"
                    value="#{deviceRegistration.selectedManufacture}" effect="fade"
                    converter="deviceManufactureConverter" style="width:200px">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{deviceRegistration.manufactureNameList}"
                        var="manufacturer" itemLabel="#{manufacturer.manufacturersName}"
                        itemValue="#{manufacturer}" />

                    <p:ajax update="deviceosName"
                        listener="#{deviceRegistration.updateOSName}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel for="deviceosName" value="Device OS Name:*"
                    style="float:right;font-size:15px;width:200px" />
                <p:spacer width="20" height="50" />


                <p:selectOneMenu id="deviceosName"
                    value="#{deviceRegistration.selectedOsName}" effect="fade"
                    converter="deviceOsNameConverter" style="width:200px">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{deviceRegistration.osNamesList}"
                        var="name" itemLabel="#{name.osName}" itemValue="#{name}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:spacer width="20" height="80" />
                    <p:commandButton id="addOsVersion" value="Add OS Version"
                        update="messages" process="os_version_panel"                    
                        actionListener="#{deviceRegistration.addOsVersion}"
                        style="float:right;" />
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: why you are not using Update in p:selectOneMenu and using ajax update?

Comment: Yes. you are not updating manufectureName. can you post managedbean and converter classes if this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Darka `<p:selectOneMenu>` doesn't have `update` attribute, `<p:ajax>` does.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes you are right. What scope you using? Maybe you can add some code from bean?